# what is function/value for updating a row with current time_stamp in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

This is my create table statement.

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BRANDS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," 
            + KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" + ")";
```

as per SQLITE document ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not allowed in column definition.

so i thought of passing KEY_UPDATED_AT values while updating a row.

```
This is my update function.

public int updateBrand(Brand brand) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, brand.getName());
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, ?????)


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_BRANDS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(brand.getId()) });
}
```

My question is what values should i put values.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, ?????), to update the row properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContentValues` object allows only literal values.

To do any kind of computation, you must use `execSQL` instead:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_BRANDS+
           " SET "+KEY_NAME+" = ?, "+
                   KEY_UPDATED_AT+" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"+
           " WHERE "+KEY_ID+" = ?",
           new Object[]{ brand.getName(), brand.getId() });
```